# Create External Table pointing to S3

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, external-tables, snowsql

How do we create an external table using Snowflake sql that points to a directory in S3? Below is the code I tried so far, but didn't work. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
create external table my_table
(
column1 varchar(4000),
column2 varchar(4000)
)
LOCATION 's3a://<externalbucket>'
```

**Note** : The file that I have in the S3 bucket is a csv file (comma seperated, double quotes enclosed and with header).

Comment: Hi - as a first step I would recommend that you read the documentation as your create statement does not follow the documented syntax: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-external-table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I sorted this out. Posting this answer as to make the answer simple to understand especially for the beginners.

Say that I have a csv file in the S3 location in the below format.

[image]

**Step 1** :

Create a file format in which you can define what type of file it is, field delimiter, data enclosed in double quotes, skip the header of the file etc.

```
create or replace file format schema_name.pipeformat
type = 'CSV' 
field_delimiter = '|' 
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
skip_header = 1
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html

**Step 2** :

Create a Stage to specify the S3 details and file format.

```
create or replace stage schema_name.stage_name 
url='s3://<path where file is kept>'
credentials=(aws_key_id='****' aws_secret_key='****')
file_format = pipeformat
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html#required-parameters

**Step 3** :

Create the external table based on the Stage name and file format.

```
create or replace external table schema_name.table_name 
(
    RollNumber INT as  (value:c1::int), 
    Name varchar(20) as ( value:c2::varchar), 
    Marks int as (value:c3::int)
)
with location = @stage_name
file_format = pipeformat
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-external-table.html

**Step 4** :

Now you should be able to query from the external table.

```
select * 
from schema_name.table_name
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to update your location to be an external stage, include the `file_format` parameter, and include the proper expression for the columns.
The location Parameter:

```
Specifies the external stage where the files containing data to be read are staged.
```

Additionally you'll need to define the `file_format`

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-external-table.html#required-parameters

So your statement should look more like this:

```
create external table my_table
(
column1 varchar as (value:c1::varchar),
column2 varchar as (value:c2::varchar)
)
location = @[namespace.]ext_stage_name[/path]
file_format = (type = CSV)
```

You may need to define additional paramaters in the file format to handle your file appropriately

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I will try and will let you know. Meanwhile can you please what should be the value for `ext_stage_name`.

Comment: See if one exists currently for the bucket/path you are looking for using the `SHOW STAGES` command
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-stages.html

If one does not exist create one with the `CRETE STAGE` command
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-stages.html